# How to scrape entire html after scripts run with jsdom

Tags: node.js, jsdom

How to **scrape** entire html after scripts run with jsdom
This is the link I want to **scrape**.
https://cma.org.sa/Market/imf/Pages/default.aspx

```
const fs = require('fs');
const jsdom = require('jsdom');
const { JSDOM } = jsdom;

const pdfUrl = 'https://cma.org.sa/Market/imf/Pages/default.aspx';

async function loadListView(){
    const dom = await JSDOM.fromURL(pdfUrl, {
        includeNodeLocations: true,
        pretendToBeVisual: true,
        runScripts: 'dangerously',
        resources: "usable",
    });
    dom.window.document.querySelectorAll('a').forEach(link => {
        console.log(link.href);
    });
    return dom;
}
loadListView()
```

My Code just gets the html before run the scripts.
But I need to __scrape__the html page after run the all scripts.
Thanks.

Comment: You need a full-fledged web browser to run the script on the site. Look for "puppeteer ".

Comment: Hi, Ricky, Yes, I have used puppeteer before, but I couldn't get the entire HTML

Comment: Now you have got a question that is easy to google. [Any method to access full html content?](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/331)

Comment: Please review my code and give me some suggestions

Comment: FYI it's _scrape_ (and _scraping_, _scraped_, _scraper_) not scrap. To scrap means to throw away like rubbish.